# Windows update cleanup not deleting on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-cleanup

I have a 111GB SSD. Out of that, I had about 500MB free.
I have moved all the applications that I can to other drives, deleted temp files and have been over AppData folder. From AppData I'd guess it's still possible to squeeze out a GB or 2.

Running disk cleanup as admin says that windows update cleanup could give me 45GB of free space. But it's not deleting anything.

At first, it was ending in an instant and nothing changed. Then I did all the pending updates, then at least it took some time to finish, but still, nothing. I disabled hibernate to gain some extra space, and tried again, still nothing.

It seems that disk cleanup does not want to remove them, even though they are obsolete. I'm out of disk space on my C: drive, and this is the last place to gain some space. How can I make it remove the old updates?

Comment: Before deleting, better analyze what takes the space. See [Best Free Disk Space Analyzer](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-space-analyzer.htm).

Comment: Done that. Only things on C drive are the OS, and the few apps that cannot  be placed elsewhere, but are needed.

Comment: You can safely delete `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution`, as Windows 8.1 doesn't get new major upgrades. See [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/software-distribution-folder-in-windows) for how.

Comment: If you are running out of space there is also the NTFS compression. For large programs or folders with compressable data (not JPEG images, videos ans such files) you can enable compression in file/folder properties and save some space.

Comment: unless i can compress OS itself, compression probably wont save me.

Comment: Removed SoftwareDistribution, used DISM, used sfc, still... nothing. WIndows folder is 40gb. Program files are 11 and 15gb. Bulk of whitch are windows aps and nvidia stuff. Everything Users and PRogram data ate botha < 5gb.

Comment: Also tried disk cleanup inside safe mode. still nothing.